# Why does strtok warn against a const?

Tags: c, string

My understanding of strtok is that it returns a pointer to the first delimiter in a char array (char*).

I get warnings against const char* as an argument, but I don't see why this matters - strtok doesn't modify the argument at all.

My understanding:

```
const char* mystring = "this, is a test";
char* endstring = strtok(mystring, ',');
char* newstring = strdup(endstring);
printf("started with: %s\n now have: %s\n", mystring, newstring);
```

Should print

```
started with: this, is a test 
now have: , is a test
```

mystring is completely untouched, sure, I have a pointer to halfway through it, but that doesn't matter. So why does strtok complain that I'm sending it a const char*?

Comment: `strtok()` actually does modify the parameter. Read the docs again :)

Comment: If you `strcpy` or `printf` from that pointer, you'll find the supplied string has been NUL terminated at the next separator character. The pointer is not as you say, to the delimitor, but to the start of the token.

Comment: @DarkAtom Thanks - the basic online examples aren't very clear on that, but that actually makes my life quite a lot easier.

Comment: Perhaps `strtok` did not find the delimitor correctly because you passed it `','` which should have been `","` (possibly including a space too). There would have been *two* compiler warnings.

Comment: @BrydonGibson Don't just look at examples. Look at the documentation too.

Comment: @klutt of course - it's just completely ignored in the examples, and it's briefly mentioned way at the end of the manpage. I guess that's my fault but you can easily learn enough about the function to write code around it while never noticing its actual behavior

Comment: @BrydonGibson Sorry if I sounded harsh. That was not my intention. I'm just saying that when you have a bug that you don't understand, it's often a very good idea to look up the proper documentation. And well, in the beginning of the man page, it says that the first argument is a non-const char pointer and that the second is a const. That in itself is a very good indication that it will be modified. Also, it's actually mentioned (at least) twice in the man page. ;)

Comment: You didn't sound harsh. I totally agree that this was my mistake/ lack of reading that got me here. It's been years since I used strtok for anything, and I thought I knew how it worked, so my own confirmation bias skewed how the docs looked

Comment: @BrydonGibson Yeah, I'm not innocent to that myself, but there are so many questions here that are so easily solved by just reading the documentation. Especially error codes returned. And basic questions about format strings. I guess I'll probably make the same mistake soon just for saying this. :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function `strtok()` modifies it's argument. The pointer returned is inside your original string. The delimiter character (in your case `,`) is replaced with a `\0` character. The next call of `strtok()` should not have a string argument, but instead a `NULL` pointer. Be careful, though: `strtok()` takes a string of delimiters as argument, not a single character:

```
strtok(s, ','); //undefined behavior, interprets the ASCII value ',' as an address
strtok(s, ","); //correct
```

### What is actually happening?

Let's analyze this string:

```
"Hello magic world!\0"
```

How do we use `strtok()` on it?

```
char s[] = "Hello magic world!"
char* first = strtok(s, " ");
char* second = strtok(NULL, " ");
char* third = strtok(NULL, " ");
```

Let's see the string after it's tokenized:

```
"Hello\0magic\0world!\0"
 ^      ^      ^
 |      |      |
first  second  third
```

You can see that the 3 pointers can be used as regular null terminated strings, but the original string is destroyed in the process. `puts(s)` now prints just `Hello".

```
printf("%s\n", s);
printf("%s %s %s\n", first, second, third);

Output:
Hello
Hello magic world!
```

Answer (score 0):

`strtok()` cannot be used on a string literal without causing potential undefined behavior. The compiler should issue a warning when you pass a `const char *` as the first argument. It is IMHO a design flaw that this not be considered an error.

Your code has another problem: you pass a character constant `','` as the second argument instead of a string `","`.

To parse constant strings, you can use `strspn` and `strcspn` that return a number of characters without modifying the string argument.

Here is an example:

```
const char *mystring = "this, is a test";
size_t n1 = strcspn(mystring, ",");
size_t n2 = strspn(mystring + n1, ",");
char *newstring = strndup(mystring, n1);
printf("started with: %s\n rest of the string: %s\n", newstring, mystring + n1 + n2);
```